# How to use rails act_as_sortable gem, with several belongs_to relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, activerecord

I have an Image model, which uses activerecord-sortable gem to easily reorder images by position.

My product model is linked to the image model, and can be re-ordered with config[:relation] option of activerecord-sortable.

It works fine, but I now want to add a Shop model, with the same relationship as product, in which images can also be reordered.

Here is my image Model

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_sortable do |config|
    config[:relation] = ->(instance) {instance.product.images}
  end
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :shop
```

Is there any way I can specify to activerecord-sortable that my Image model must use several relationships ?

I have tried that :

```
  acts_as_sortable do |config|
    config[:relations] = [->(instance) {instance.product.images}, ->(instance) {instance.product.images}]
  end
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a word in documentation about multiple nested models.

I know that such case implemented in ranked-model gem: https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model